# Django MongoDB Migration Warnings

Tags: python, django, mongodb, database-migration, djongo

```
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using CONSTRAINT" fully. Visit https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
 OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial...This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using KEY" fully. Visit https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using REFERENCES" fully. Visit https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
 OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name...This version of djongo does not support "COLUMN DROP NOT NULL " fully. Visit https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
This version of djongo does not support "DROP CASCADE" fully. Visit https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
 OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

*I'm trying to connect Django with MongoDB database.*
***Why am I getting these warnings while migrating?***

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/132) helps with your issue?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB isn't supported by the Django project itself, only via the Djongo adapter.

Those models/migrations use certain Django core features that Djongo doesn't support at present, as is rather obvious from the error message.

Comment: Actually this messages are from `Djongo` adapter, not `Django`.

Comment: @Charnel Er, yes?

Comment: `MongoDB isn't supported by the Django project itself, only via the Djongo adapter` - I mean this person is already using `Djongo` adopter and they are raised not by `Django` but `Djongo`, probably because of wrong lib version intalled.

Comment: I would think the errors are caused by Djongo not supporting some of the features those Django migrations would require.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but you can solve the problem with installing specific pymongo version.

Try this one:

```
pip install pymongo==3.12.1 --upgrade
```

Then try to make migrations again.

Comment: I am using the same version of pymongo then too getting the warning:
This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using CONSTRAINT" fully.
This version of djongo does not support "NULL, NOT NULL column validation check" fully.
This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using KEY" fully. 
This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using REFERENCES" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/

-- What version of DRF and Djongo is compatible to use with pymongo=3.12.1?

-- I am using djangorestframework==3.14.0, djongo==1.3.6